# Emulator is running error even though I deleted lock files

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to launch my app on my emulator, but it says "Emulator is already running. If that's not the case, go to the .lock files and delete them".

I tried deleting the lock files, using another emulator, using another API but it still doesn't work. It worked until yesterday when I installed the Multi-OS Plugin. However, even if I disable the plugin, I still get the error now. In addition, I just set up Google Admob for my app.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out only that specific app isn't working. When I try running other apps, it works. This was because I forgot to set up my billing info for the Google Admob and so all the ads were disabled. As a result, it was glitching when I tried to run it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Cold Reboot it will help you to get out of this situation.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. The cold boot opens up the emulator, but it still says the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Kill the ADB server and reinstalling Intel HAXM will help.